# Passing information between buttons

Tags: java

I have an assignment where I have to click a button 1 in panel 1 and change the information on button 2 in panel 2, however I cannot figure out how to pass the information.

I thought I might be able to pass the information from method b() from panel2 back to one but that's not working.

I'm pretty stuck and don't know how to move forward with the program. Any help is appreciated.

Panel1

```
public class MyJPanel1 extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    Student st1 = new student("Fred","Fonseca",44);

    JButton j = new JButton(st1.getInfo());
    JButton b1 = new JButton("..");

    public myJPanel1() {
        super();
        setBackground(Color.yellow);
        // the whatsUp of this student has to shown in the other panel
        j.addActionListener(this); 
        add(j);         
    }   
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {         
        Object obj = event.getSource();
        //=====================================                            
            if (obj == j){
                b1.setText(st1.whatsUp()); // Output on JButton in JPanel2 
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

Panel2

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class myJPanel2 extends JPanel {
    JButton j1 = new JButton("");

    public void b(JButton b1) {
        JButton j1 = b1;            
    }   
    public myJPanel2() {
        super();
        setBackground(Color.pink);
        setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));
        add(j1);
        // j1.setText(b1);
    }

 }
```

Comment: Here's your hint: the part of the code that sends information from the button you push to the button you want to change has to KNOW about both buttons.

Comment: Can you clarify a bit? I thought that method b should swap out the information in j1 to the information in j2. Anything I try in the actionperformed doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Create a method in `MyJPanel2` which sets the text in `JButton`.

```
public class myJPanel2 extends JPanel {
    JButton button = new JButton("");

    ...........

    public void setButtonText(String text) {
        button.setText(text);
    }
}
```

In `MyJPanel2`, you need to store a reference of `MyJPanel1`. Then just call the `setButtonText` in the `ActionListener`

```
public class MyJPanel1 extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    private MyJPanel2 panel;

    public MyJPanel1(MyJPanel2 panel) {
        this.panel = panel;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {                       
            if (obj == j){
                panel.setButtonText(yourText);
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple things to keep in mind. Java is an Object Oriented language, meaning that you want define your Objects using Classes, and then reuse those objects as much as possible. If you have two panels, each one containing a button, then that is the perfect time to *define* the Class once

```
public class MyPanel extends JPanel{
  protected JButton button;

  public MyPanel(String buttonName){
    button = new JButton(buttonName);
  }
  //etc etc etc
}
```

and then use the Class over and over

```
public class MyProgram {
  protected MyPanel panel1;
  protected MyPanel panel2;

  public MyProgram(){
    panel1 = new MyPanel("Button 1");
    panel2 = new MyPanel("Button 2");
  }
  //etc etc
}
```

Now, once you have your program set up like this, it is very easy to communicate between the two panels, since in *MyProgram* you have both instances of your panels available.

So, lets say your *MyPanel* class had a method called *setButtonText*

```
public void setButtonText(String text){
  button.setText(text);
}
```

You could call this method in your *MyProgram* in order to change the text on one of the buttons

```
myPanel1.setText("New Button 1 text");
```

But how do we know if the button in *myPanel1* or *myPanel2* was pushed? You can look into how Java uses [ActionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html) to communicate events between different objects.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If I write sea you don't have connected that two panels together. The best way to coonect them together is from thrid calass wher you declare this two clasess. And set this two classes eachOther. 
Example:

```
class conecctor{

ClassA first;
ClassB secod;
    public void init(){
    {
        first=new ClassA();
        second=new ClassB();
        first.setClasB(second);
        second.setClasA(first);
    }
}
class ClassA{
    ClassB classB;
    public void setClassB(ClassB classB){
       this.classB=classB;
    }
}
class ClassB{
    ClassA classA;
    public void setClassA(ClassA classA){
       this.classA=classA;
    }
}
```

And then when you have instances in each class you can call all public methods from evrywher.

Beter way is to create interface and just pass the interface (listener) steal you pass whole class if that clas implements interface but it its more clearly and other advatages.